# How to transfer controller in tabview controller after click on save button swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I wanted to transfer controller in tab view 2 after click on save button. 
I'm using Tab bar controller how to redirect view one controller to tab bar controller.

Here is my save button code.

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
print("send")
// value saved in the database after save value i want to redirect inthe tab controller.


}
```

[image]

I want to redirect in create tab controller.

Can anyone suggest me how to redirect?
Thanks!!

Comment: "I want to redirect in create tab controller." From where ?

Comment: Umair, In the create tab button I opened the new controller and in the controller i have a send button i wanted if i click on the send button i will come back again in the create controller.

Comment: from createViewController you are pushing a viewController ? Or presenting it ?

Comment: if you are pushing the just popViewController on button click, And if you are presenting then just dismiss the viewController on button click

Comment: _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Comment: I redirect to newViewController using to segue. In the newViewController i want to come back in the tabBar controller(createController.)

Comment: @sohil, This is working , Can you inform me how to change selected tab create to outbox?

Comment: Sorry I don't Understand what you say?

Comment: I have an another controller is newViewController. I want to redirect my view screen newViewController to any one of three controller see in the screen (Inbox,Outbox,Create). How can i will redirect the view?